# python multiprocessing manager cannot load list from distributed node

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

**After serveral test, I find this problem caused by the dim of `manager.list(manager.list(...))`. But I really need it to be 2 dims. Any suggestion would be appreciated!**

I'm trying to build a server and multiple clients **across multiple nodes**.

One node act as server which initial `manager.list()` for other client to use.

Other nodes act as client which attach server to get list and deal with it.

Firewall is closed. **And when put server and client on a single node, it works fine.**

Got problem like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 352, in <module>
    train(args)
  File "main.py", line 296, in train
    args, proc_manager, device)
  File "main.py", line 267, in make_gossip_buffer
    mng,sync_freq=args.sync_freq, num_nodes=args.num_nodes)
  File "/home/think/gala-master-distprocess-changing_to_multinodes/gala/gpu_gossip_buffer.py", line 49, in __init__
    r_events = read_events[rank]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __getitem__
  File "/home/think/anaconda3/envs/AC/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 819, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
  File "/home/think/anaconda3/envs/AC/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "/home/think/anaconda3/envs/AC/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 943, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
  File "/home/think/anaconda3/envs/AC/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 793, in __init__
    self._incref()
  File "/home/think/anaconda3/envs/AC/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 847, in _incref
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/home/think/anaconda3/envs/AC/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 492, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/home/think/anaconda3/envs/AC/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 620, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Server runs on a single node.
Code of server are shown below:

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import ListProxy, BarrierProxy, AcquirerProxy, EventProxy
from gala.arguments import get_args
mp.current_process().authkey = b'abc'

def server(manager,host, port, key, args):
    read_events = manager.list([manager.list([manager.Event() for _ in range(num_learners)])
                            for _ in range(num_learners)]) 
    manager.register('get_read_events', callable=lambda : read_events, proxytype=ListProxy)
    print('start service at', host)
    s = manager.get_server()
    s.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    args = get_args()
    manager = mp.Manager()
    server(manager,'10.107.13.120', 5000, b'abc', args)
```

Client runs on other nodes. those nodes connect server with ethernet. CLient ip is 10.107.13.80

Code of client are shown below:

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
mp.current_process().authkey = b'abc'

def make_gossip_buffer(mng):
    read_events = mng.get_read_events()
    gossip_buffer = GossipBuffer(parameters)
 
def train(args): 
    proc_manager = mp.Manager()
    proc_manager.register('get_read_events')
    proc_manager.__init__(address=('10.107.13.120', 5000), authkey=b'abc')
    proc_manager.connect()
    make_gossip_buffer(proc_manager)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    train(args)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: multiprocessing managers don't seem to handle mutable objects within lists or dictionaries well. In theory using nested proxy objects should work, but there have been [bugs](https://bugs.python.org/issue6766) in the actual execution of this... it seems possible there's an implementation bug in storing an event proxy inside a nested list proxy.

Comment: If what you need is an nxm array of `Event`'s, you might be better off replicating the functionality with a socket server and passing messages to represent the  using a simple custom protocol. This will be at least as fast as real `Event` objects being sent over the network if not faster.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Aaron, accroding to [https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html] 17.2.2.8. **However, storing a value in a container proxy (which triggers a __setitem__ on the proxy object) does propagate through the manager and so to effectively modify such an item, one could re-assign the modified value to the container proxy. This approach is perhaps less convenient than employing nested Proxy Objects for most use cases but also demonstrates a level of control over the synchronization.** It seems nested List proxy could work, but it doesn't

Comment: I'm curious how you manage to start your server code without `ProcessError("Already started server")` being called because you try to `get_server` and `serve_forever` on a manager which is already started.

Comment: That is beacuse, we create manager at ```main()``` but pass it to function ```server```. We initize manager which we created before and run it in ```server```

Comment: calling `mp.Manager` directly instead of `SyncManager` calls `start` right after creation. you can't call `manager.list` or `Event` on a manager which hasn't been started yet. so it's "started" twice, which there's a check against. It should raise a ProcessError as written.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Aaron, I started the manager right after it was created, but it won't work